# Nested lambda expressions and string cultures

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'm trying to do a nested lambda expression like to following:

```
textLocalizationTable.Where(
  z => z.SpokenLanguage.Any(
    x => x.FromCulture == "en-GB")
  ).ToList();
```

but i get the error:

```
Member access 'System.String FromCulture' of 
'DomainModel.Entities.SpokenLanguage' not legal on type
'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[DomainModel.Entities.SpokenLanguage].
```

TextLocalization has this relation to spokenlanguage:

```
[Association(OtherKey = "LocalizationID", ThisKey = "LocalizationID", Storage = "_SpokenLanguage")]
private EntitySet<SpokenLanguage> _SpokenLanguage = new EntitySet<SpokenLanguage>();
public EntitySet<SpokenLanguage> SpokenLanguage
{
     set { _SpokenLanguage = value; }
     get { return _SpokenLanguage; }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

---

I have tried your suggestion with the same error.

Spokenlanguage now has this association:

```
    internal EntityRef<TextLocalization> _TextLocalization;
    [Association(ThisKey = "LocalizationID", OtherKey = "LocalizationID", Storage = "_TextLocalization")]
    public TextLocalization TextLocalization
    {
        get { return _TextLocalization.Entity; }
        internal set { _TextLocalization.Entity = value; LocalizationID = value.LocalizationID; }
    }
```

On the datacontext this is added:

```
        DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
        dlo.LoadWith<TextLocalization>(text => text.SpokenLanguage);
        dc.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

Any  further ideas? Mayby it just me misunderstood some fundamental stuff??

Comment: Is this actually a LINQ to SQL question? This may have nothing to do with nested lambdas per se, which I tend to use abundantly...

Comment: What happens if you try "textLocalizationTable.Where(z => z.SpokenLanguage.Where(x => x.FromCulture == "en-GB").Count() > 0).ToList();"?

Comment: Can you show the `SpokenLanguage` class, at least the property in question?

Comment: A bit of topic, but try renaming the `SpokenLanguage` property to `SpokenLanguages`, since that better describes what it is; a collection of multiple `SpokenLanguage` objects.

Comment: Same error with Kurresmack code.

The SpokenLanguge FromCulture property:

    [Table(Name="ep_text_spokenLanguage")]
public class SpokenLanguage
{      
    [Column]
    public string FromCulture { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is definitely an issue with "Linq to SQL" and most likely the association.

Here are a couple suggestions:

- You don't mention if you use the
  [AssociationAttribute] set on your
  child table, you will need it if it's not present.
- You will probably have to use DataLoadOptions on your DataContext, so the child table is loaded when the parent table is queried.
- In the *set* method of an Entity< T> property, I would use _SpokenLanguage.Assign(value) instead of _SpokenLanguage = value